# Is Sohma House a literal house where all the families live?

Tags: fruits-basket

In Fruits Basket, is Sohma house an actual house where all of the families with a member cursed by the zodiac live, or is it more of a gated community situation where the families all live together, but they're in separate houses near each other? The exception being Shigure, who lives in an isolated house that still happens to be on Sohma property.

Comment: From the manga, I seem to remember the Sohma main house actually being a gigantic mansion where a bunch of people live together in one house.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I greatly appreciate it. I've never read the manga, but I love the show. It's a favorite of mine. :)

Comment: Conversely, I've only seen one episode of the show but I read the first eleven volumes or so of the manga. You'd probably enjoy it if you like the anime. I believe the anime story was pretty faithful to the manga.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is a main house, but it is not where they *all* live. Rather, the Sohma Estate is a walled community (referred to as the "inside") where there are many houses. Most of the Zodiac families live inside the walls, but not at the main house. Kagura and Hiro, for instance, are shown to live in their own homes.

From https://fruitsbasket.fandom.com/wiki/Sohma_Estate :

> There is a total of about 150 people living within the Sohma estate. Within the main estate itself live only 50 people of those who know about the curse; as in the head of the family, the Cursed Sohmas, their relatives, and the maids surrounding them. Those who are unbeknownst to the curse, which makes up the remaining 100 people, live “outside” of said main estate.

[image: Sohma Estate]

Also see https://fruitsbasket.fandom.com/wiki/Sohma_Family